# Social share function not working with expend

Tags: html, css, button, social-media

I have a five list social share button which is click to expend right side, the social icon not visible when expend I need social icon in list left to right after expend the function and when expending social share icon will rotate, I have attached image for reference, please check. Thanks in advance

[image]

```css
.social-share-overlay a.overlay-button {
  color: #328487;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
.social-share-overlay a.overlay-button i {
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: block;
}
.social-share-overlay a.overlay-button p {
  display: none;
}
.social-share-overlay a.overlay-button:hover {
  width: 190px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
.social-share-overlay a.overlay-button:hover p {
  display: inline;
}
.social-share-overlay a.overlay-button.facebook {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    display: flex;
}
.social-share-overlay a.overlay-button.facebook li i {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper-s">

  <div class="social-share-overlay">
    <a class="overlay-button facebook" href="">
      <i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <li><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add the css `link`, add the link, then remove all `<li>` , see if it works

Comment: Thanks for your reply and given your prompt time, much appreciated!, I did as per your suggestion but all list moved to out of the expend part.